# How to eliminate extra white space before and after text through javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to ask a question! But my English is not good. I will try my best to describe my problem completely!

Today there is a p tag, and the text inside will be brought in from the back end. I hope to eliminate the extra white space before and after, no Do you know whether it can be easily achieved with CSS?

Should I still use javascript to achieve this? But I don’t know much about javascript. I hope someone can share how to use javascript to solve this problem~ But I hope is a better CSS solution.

```css
.demo {
  white-space: pre;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">
  
  
   lorem
   test
   demo
  
  
</p>
```

Comment: `the text inside will be brought in from the back end` sanitise the data at the source, not the output, in other words, remove the whitespace from the string on the server. If you absolutely have to do it in JS then use `$('p').text((i, t) => t.trim());`

Comment: @Peter B 
Thank you for your reply. Can you help me see how it is written?
https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/yLXNBPZ

Comment: What do i and t stand for?
I'm sorry that my programming is very poor.

Comment: `i` is the index of the element, `t` is its text value. More info in the jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function

Comment: understand thank you for sharing this with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `trim()` function:

```js
myString = "  abc   "
console.log(myString.trim())
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like that

```
function someFun(){
 const element = doucument.getElementById("requiredElement");
 element.innerText= element.value.trim();
}
```